# HTML5 video source will not successfully change in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-video

I'm going nuts over this problem. I have a script that changes the sources of a `<video>` tag, then reloads it and plays it. The problem is that I just can't get it to work on any version of Internet Explorer.

I have an array of video sources called `sequence.sources`, containing:

```
sequence.sources = ['video.webm', 'video.mp4', 'video.ogv'];
```

The `sequences` object is loaded from another array, so that's the dynamic aspect of it all. The function I use to change the video sources is as follows:

```
var videoElem = document.getElementById('video');

// Remove all sources
while (videoElem.firstChild) {
    videoElem.removeChild(video.firstChild);
}

// Add new sources
for (var i = 0; i < sequence.sources.length; i++) {
   var srcElem = document.createElement('source');
   srcElem.setAttribute('src', sequence.sources[i]);
   videoElem.appendChild(srcElem);
}

// Initiate video
videoElem.load();
videoElem.play();
```

This works perfectly on all browsers but IE. What am I to do? I've already tried modifying the `src` attribute of the `<video>` tag directly, but that doesn't seem to work. I've even tried removing the entire `<video>` tag and adding a new one with the updated sources. No cigar.

This is possibily off topic, but I'm considering the possibility that I must add some .htaccess hack to make it work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My final thought is that all sources except the first one are somehow faulty and won't be played. Is there some way I can check their compatibility with IE?

**EDIT:** Network tab on developer tools give me `206 partial` as result of the http request. This is highly likely to be an encoding compatibility issue. I will probably close this question soon if that proves to be the case.

Comment: have you tried using the same source video multiple times in the array?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? The video element is not implemented in IE 8. Have a look here: http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie08.html

Comment: In your code you have `videoElem`, but then use a mix of `video` and `videoElem` - are they both valid?

Comment: @unicorn2: I'm using IE 10. @veritasetratio: thanks, now it's only `videoElem`, that error was just in the question, not in the code.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you create `source` nodes and then try to change the `src` attribute. That does not work in IE. Instead only use the `src` attribute. A complete solution can be found in my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7905151/818732 ... try to google such things and add "stackoverflow" to get the best results.

By the way: have you ever tried just adding the mp4 file directly as an attribute (in the html code)? if yes and it still does not work check if your server returns the correct mime-type for .mp4 files (`video/mp4`).

Last but not least - utilize caniuse.com to check for browser support. For starters, here is the link for mp4s: http://caniuse.com/mpeg4

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer, have an upvote. Actually, I've tried all the things you suggest. I even used your answer to that other question! The only conclusion I can draw at this point is that the encoding of every video file except the first one is unsupported in IE.

Comment: that is possible. I tend to re-encode every video I get before it's put on a website to reduce such problems... BTW: you dont need webm AND ogv. That's simply redundant. I personally go for webm and mp4 though ogv and mp4 will probably have the same effect at the time of writing (again, caniuse.com helps here)