# Javascript to stop HTML5 video download, restore source when video is played

Tags: javascript, html5-video, modal-dialog

I'm working on a page that has multiple HTML5 video elements that popup in CSS modal boxes when a link is clicked. The page originally would begin download of every video on the page, but, after finding similar topics here, I was able to set the source to be src="", allowing the page to load quickly. 
I'm having difficulty now trying to restore the download when a user selects a video and it pops up in the modal box.

I'm not new to Javascript, but I'm also not proficient. Ideally, each video source should be set to "", then when the video is opened, the video should reload. I also added a function to pause the video when the modal is closed as it used to continue playing. Any help or criticism is appreciated, I'm here to learn. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="image" style="float:left;margin:0;"><a href = "#layers" id="showModal"><img src="video-image.png" alt="Play visualization" width="150"/><br />Layers</a>
    <div id="layers" class="modalDialog">
        <div> 
            <a href="#close" class="close" id="closeModal">Close</a>
            <h3>Layers</h3>
            <video id="videoContainer" class="videoContainer" loop="loop" style="width:698px;">
                <source src="video-file.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
                <source src="video-file.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
                <source src="video-file.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 for(var i=0; i< 20; i++)
 {
     document.getElementsByTagName("video")[i].src="";
 }
 $("#showModal").click(function() {
    var videoID = document.getElementsById("showModal").getAttribute('href');
    var videoElement = document.getElementsById(videoID).getElementsByTagName("video");
    videoElement.load();

    });

    $("#closeModal").click(function() {
        $("#videoContainer")[0].pause();             
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151606/setattribute-and-video-src-for-changing-video-tag-source-not-working-in-ie9) is maybe related.

Dont have your files but got it working using the following code:

```
 <video id="videoContainer" class="videoContainer" style="width:698px;">  
   <source id="mp4Source" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>


$("#showModal").click(function () {
    var videoID = document.getElementById("showModal").getAttribute('href');
    var videoElement = document.getElementById("layers").getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    var srcID = document.getElementById("mp4Source");

    videoElement.src = srcID.getAttribute("src");
    videoElement.load();
    videoElement.play();
});
```