# Html5 video tag - to play a local video downloaded in every 5 minutes

Tags: nginx, video, chromium

on my laptop I have running nginx web server.

So this is a localhost web page.

I created a cron job to download in every 5 minutes a video from a web site. So the downloaded video could be changed when on the remote web site someone changes the video - which be then downloaded to my laptop as a new video but with same name.

I expect that that in my web browser Chromium the video changes too when the downloaded video just changed.

But that is not happaning. My browser shows always the first downloaded video although it has changed since then.

The cronjob is this:
*/5 * * * * rm /var/www/localhost/htdocs/radar.mp4 & wget -O /var/www/localhost/htdocs/radar.mp4 https://www.idokep.hu/radar/radar.mp4

The html5 video tag is this:

```
<video autoplay loop width="800">
<source src="radar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

How can I achive that that I get the downloaded and changed video in my web browser?

Best, Pal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the browser to not cache, but it is set in the header so applies to the entire page which is not what you want most likely.

You can also set the response header on the server side to set the time to live to be less than 5 minutes. See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Here you are relying on the browser to properly respect this, which may not always be the case.

As an extra precaution, you can simply append a time stamp or a random number to your video file name so that the browser sees it as a new file and will definitely download it. This is probably the safest approach if you want to guarantee it will not be cached.

Comment: I have changed the cronjob like this:  */5 * * * * wget --no-use-server-timestamps -O /var/www/localhost/htdocs/radar.mp4 https://www.idokep.hu/radar/radar.mp4 so the file radar.mp4 has now the local timestamp, i.e. when it was downloaded, so it's timestamp is changing now in every five minutes. But in my browser I still can see the first downloaded radar.mp4 video which was downloaded yesterday. Why?

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood you, the video file name and url still is the same for the video file from the point of view of the browser? If so, the browser most likely just thinks its is the same video. You can provide a URL for the video which your local server can then resolve to an actual filename, and have the file name include the timestamp so each video file will be unique.

Comment: Hello Mike! Thank you very much for the help! I do not understand Your last question and last advice. Sorry, my first language is not English. Still I am trying hard to understand your advice. The filename is still the same, namely 'radar.mp4', and the file is still in  /var/www/localhost/htdocs/ directory. How can I provide a URL for the video, and so on?

Comment: I just put this into my webpage: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" "pragma" content="no-cache" /> so I hope this solve my problem.

Comment: I put these into <head> tag:    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
   <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
   <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">

Comment: Just to understand, are you reloading the browser page when the new video is downloaded or just leaving it with the video looping in the background?

Comment: Hello Mike! Thank you for the question. When the new video is downloaded - and this is happening every 5 minutes - I do not reload the browser page. I just leave the page with the video looping in the background. Nevertheless, if I reload the page, still I see not the new video just downloaded, but the old video that is looping in the background on the browser page.

Comment: I can see the new video if I do F12 / Empty Cache and hard reload.

Comment: I think for your case it is easiest to add some script to set the source - see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12448053/334402. I would start by just reloading the video (i.e. player.load()) and seeing if that works for you across browsers and if not, then save the video to different file names, e.g. with a timestamp or random number appended to the name when downloaded, and add some script to query the latest file name to use and then load that.

Comment: I create a script which reload the video with `player.load();` but that is not enough. I have now cron job which download every 5 minutes the video and append timestamp to its filename, moreover, the cron job removes older downloaded files, so there is always remain only one video file. The filename of this video file is changing every 5 minutes. Now how to write such Java script which should change the filename in the source html tag inside the video tag?

Comment: I created now a bash script that contains in it a sed command. That sed command substitute the old video filename with the new one in the <source > attribute of the video html tag. I think I solved this problem, but not sure. I am waiting the new video file to be appeared and then shall I see whether is this working, or not.

Comment: Also, I added this to the nginx.conf `# assets, media
    location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aa
    expires 4m;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=280";
    access_log off;
    }`