# can you dynamically change the video based on vuex state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-video, nuxt.js

I have a small web app, it fakes looking like facetime. I want to switch the video elements via clicking a "next" button which will update a value in vuex and the video will be swapped out accordingly. I've tried this way:

```
<video autoplay playsinline loop muted class="background-video__source"> 
      <source v-if="currentIndex === 0" src="~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source v-if="currentIndex === 1" src="~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source v-if="currentIndex === 2" src="~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source v-if="currentIndex === 3" src="~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The above method works in the ios simulator in safari but not on desktop chrome.

I've also tried this method:

```
    <video v-if="currentIndex === 0" autoplay playsinline loop muted class="background-video__source"> 
      <source src="~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video v-if="currentIndex === 1" autoplay playsinline loop muted class="background-video__source"> 
      <source src="~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video v-if="currentIndex === 2" autoplay playsinline loop muted class="background-video__source"> 
      <source src="~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video v-if="currentIndex === 3" autoplay playsinline loop muted class="background-video__source"> 
      <source src="~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But this method works nowhere.

Worst case, I can use GIFs instead of video but video would just perform better.

**Prior SO questions:**

The questions posted about this previously refer you to updating the source like `<video autoplay playsinline loop muted :src="someVarSource" class="background-video__source">`. I have had no luck with this approach however.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12448053/392102) indicates that you should change the `src` attribute, and call `player.load()` and `player.play()` after making the change.

Comment: have you tried to bind src attribute instead ? like `<source :src="'~assets/img/placeholder/placeholder-' + (currentIndex + 1) + '.mp4'" type="video/mp4">`

Comment: @JulienMetral sadly that method isn't working for me either

Comment: @RoyJ that's not an example of loading the asset from vuex, and my above code (first snippet) worked without explicitly calling any pause() or play() methods in iOS but then didn't work in chrome

Comment: It doesn't matter where you load the asset from. The issue is with the `<video>` element, and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a video player that allows you to dynamically switch out the content. I made a `v-reload` directive that, when the selection changes, calls `load` on the player, which causes it to recognize the changed `src` attribute.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'main',
  data: {
    selected: 0,
    sources: [
      'https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-SD.mp4',
      'http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
    ]
  },
  directives: {
    reload(el, binding) {
      if (binding.oldValue !== binding.value) {
        el.load();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<main>
  <div v-for="s, i in sources">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" :value="i" v-model="selected">
      {{s}}
    </label>
  </div>
  <video controls v-reload="selected">
      <source :src="sources[selected]" type="video/mp4" media="all"> 
      <p>Sorry, there's a problem playing this video. Please try using a different browser.</p>
  </video>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `src` attribute dynamic and change the data on button click.

Something like this:

```
<video autoplay playsinline loop muted class="background-video__source"> 
  <source :src="'~assets/img/placeholder/' + currentSource" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    currentIndex: 0,
    currentSource: "placeholder-0.mp4",
    sources: [
      {id: 0, name: "placeholder-0.mp4"}
      {id: 1, name: "placeholder-1.mp4"}
      {id: 2, name: "placeholder-2.mp4"}
      {id: 3, name: "placeholder-3.mp4"}
    ]
  }
},
methods: {
  changeVideo () {
    // check if it was't the last video source in the list and change the video 
    if (sources[this.currentIndex + 1] != undefined) {
      this.currentIndex += 1
      this.currentSource = sources[this.currentIndex + 1].name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I could go this route i think but it doesn't tie into the vuex store i've got set up and i feel like the functionality would be split if i'm independently determining index via data() instead of grabbing it from my vuex store

Comment: @StephenTetreault well, that's an example, just move all the things from `data()` to your store and get / commit values to / from the store instead. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: i do and its what i'm currently doing but its just not working for some reason. it only works in safari on the ios simulator, but then freezes up after a while. i've decided to go with background GIFs and that has been working well as opposed to background video elements.