# Video doesn't load after changing src

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a page with a (image) button and a video element. Whenever I click the button, I want to load and start playing a random video. However, even though `src` gets set correctly to a random file, the video player does not change. What could be the problem? The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="all">
            <div id="video-container">
                <video width="500" controls>
                    <source id="vid" src="videos/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div id="buton">
                <img src="img/buton.png" onclick="swapVid()">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function swapVid() {
                console.log("videos/"+Math.round(Math.random() * 3).toString() + ".mp4")
                document.getElementById("vid").setAttribute("src", "videos/"+Math.round(Math.random() * 3).toString() + ".mp4")
                console.log(document.getElementById("vid").getAttribute("src"))
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not replace the `<video />`  element completely?

Comment: Have you tried the solution on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151606/setattribute-and-video-src-for-changing-video-tag-source-not-working-in-ie9 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it without replacing the existing video element as listed below. For this the `id="vid"` should be an attribute of `<video>` element. I suppose this is what you tried to do:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="video-container">
        <video width="500" controls id="vid" src="videos/1.mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
    </div>
        <div id="buton">
              <img src="img/buton.png" onclick="swapVid()">
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapVid() {
        var nextVideo = "videos/" + Math.round(Math.random() * 3).toString() + ".mp4";
        document.getElementById("vid").setAttribute("src", nextVideo);
        console.log(document.getElementById("vid").getAttribute("src"));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could take a different approach to this problem, by replacing the existing video with an entirely new video element:

```
function swapVid() {

    var video = document.getElementById('vid');
    if(video) { video.remove(); }

    video = document.createElement('video');
    video.setAttribute('id', 'vid'); 
    video.width = 500;
    video.src = "videos/"+ parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + ".mp4";
}
```

Taking this approach ensures that no "stale" state (ie play state, cursor position, etc) from prior video playback carries over to next randomly selected video.